# NSTableview reloadDataForRowIndexes sounds in mac

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2

I am developing an app for Mac, I am getting a weird issue. When ever i reload a row and for a particular column when the reload code executes i am getting a sound output from my mac.

Below is the code

```
myTableView.reloadDataForRowIndexes(myTableView.selectedRowIndexes, columnIndexes: NSIndexSet.init(index: myTableView.columnWithIdentifier("source")))
```

I have a column with identifier "source", When ever i try to reload and after the execution of the above line i am getting sound in my mac.

I am using Xcode 7.3, OSX 10.11.6

Comment: Can you describe the sound?

Comment: Does this only happen When debugging in Xcode, or also when you run the executable by itself? It highly possible that there's an Xcode behaviour with a sound enabled. e.g. `Open the Xcode Preferences > Behaviors` and one of those is causing the sound. By default, none of the behaviours play a sound.

Comment: @rocky, its the sound when you press "Cmd + z" in xcode when there are not changes to undo.

Comment: @rocky, i found the name of the sound its "Funk".

Comment: @AdrianSluyters, i didn't changed any thing in the preferences.

Comment: does this only happen when debugging though Xcode? Or does it also happen when you build the app and run it directly from the executable.

Comment: @AdrianSluyters, I figured the root cause of this issue. When ever i am calling NSTextfield.insertText("Some string"), i am getting this sound. I fixed this now by removing this line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the issue. I debugged the code in depth and found the root cause.

Sound is coming when ever i am calling below code, here sourceTextField is a NSTextField. I commented this code and every thing is working fine.(i can directly give the value to text field like sourceTextField.stringValue.)

```
sourceTextField.insertText(itemText)
```

Thanks to all of you who made some time to write a comment/ post a message, Sorry for bothering you all guys.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a breakpoint on NSBeep()? My gues would be that the table, or some other code trigger by the update is sending an error message.

Comment: i am not using NSBeep() anywhere. I fixed the issue and posted as answer in this thread.